# How do I create an associate array in jquery and send it via ajax to get parsed with php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

How would I make an associative array (or some comparable alternative) in jQuery AND send that array via ajax to a php page so that I can use php to handle it?

Something like this...

```
// jQuery

if($something == true) {
    data[alt] = $(this).attr('alt');
    data[src] = $(this).attr('src');
else if ($something == "something else") {
    data[html] = $(this).html();
}
```

Then, send this array using the .ajax() function

```
// jQuery

$.ajax({
    data: /* somehow send my array here */,
    type: 'POST',
    url: myUrl,
    complete: function(){
        // I'll do something cool here
    }
});
```

Finally, parse this data with php...

```
// php

<img alt="<?PHP echo $_POST['alt']; ?>" src="<?PHP echo $_POST['src']; ?>" />
```

I've done a little googling on the subject and have read that you cannot make an associative array with javascript so I'm really just looking for some alternative. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the data as an object to [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), like this:

```
var data = {};
if ($something == true) {
    data.alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    data.src = $(this).attr('src');
}else if ($something == "something else") {
    data.html = $(this).html();
}

$.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    url: myUrl,
    complete: function(){
        // I'll do something cool here
    }
});
```

This will get serialized for the post, internally using [`$.param(obj)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to convert it for the POST, for example:

```
alt=thisAlt&src=thisSrc
```

or:

```
html=myEncodedHtml
```

Comment: How would I get echo these out with php?

Comment: @Johnny - Like you already have in the question, e.g. `$_POST['alt']`

Answer (score 0):

Won't it be simpler to just send some json to the php side, then use the json_decode function in php to get an associative array on the php side?

Answer (score 0):

Associative array is sortof a PHP thing. But you can have something similar via curly braces ({}). In fact, you're already using it in your `$.ajax()` call. Notice the '{}' parts. In this case, you can use `json_decode()` in the PHP server to decode the 'data' parameter:

```
 $.ajax({  
     url: myUrl,  
     data: {   foo: 0,   bar: 1,   baz: 2   }, 
     success: function() {   }, 
     dataType: 'json'  
 });
```

`

Using json_decode() will get you something like:

`php
array('foo' => 0, 'bar' => 1, 'baz' => 2);`

Comment: How would I add a key/value one at a time like in my code above?

Comment: var data = {}; data['foo'] = 0;